# Distance difference between Pyproj and Haversine

Tags: python, pyproj, haversine

I'm measuring the distance between two points with two different methods. This results in two very different results. Please have a look:

```
from pyproj import Transformer
from haversine import haversine, Unit

coordinate_to_meters = Transformer.from_crs('epsg:4326', 'epsg:3857')
transformed_w = coordinate_to_meters.transform(40.7004, -74.0164)
transformed_e = coordinate_to_meters.transform(40.7004, -73.9232)

print(transformed_e[0] - transformed_w[0])
# Result: 10374.976541933604

print(haversine((40.7004, -74.0164), (40.7004, -73.9232), unit=Unit.METERS))
# Result: 7856.787789520122
```

The second result looks right, but I want to use the first method (`pyproj`). So, how can I make `pyproj` return the correct distance?

Comment: The issue is the transformation to EPSG:3857, which is absolutely useless for distance measures due to its massive distortion. Use e.g. the [Geoid.inv](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/geod.html#pyproj.Geod.inv) function instead.

Comment: Okay. My thought was: Because I want to use a grid in the next step, pyproj can help me creating such.